# How to prevent axis off from removing the subtitle?

Tags: matlab, plot, subtitle

How to prevent `axis off` from removing the subtitle? Nemely, I just want to remove the x, y axes but not the subtitle itself.

```
img = imread('cameraman.tif');
figure;
imagesc(img);
title('A');
subtitle('B');
```

If I add `axis off` at the end it gives me: (The subtitle `B` is gone...)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
img = imread('cameraman.tif');
figure;
imagesc(img);
title('A');
subtitle('B');
set(gca,'xtick',[]);
set(gca,'xticklabel',[]);
set(gca,'ytick',[]);
set(gca,'yticklabel',[]);
```